# MySQL Inner Join 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON  a.someColumn = b.otherColumn
INNER JOIN tableC c
ON b.anotherColumn = c.nextColumn
```

What if tableA and tableB has the same name in fields? How can I use:

```
<?
$name = mysql_fetch...
echo $name['a.title'] . ' ' . $name['b.title'];
?>
```

So I could get title from tableA and title from tableB. Because now, if use just `$name['title']` it returns tableA's title. And the above code unfortunately gives just an empty string.

Comment: It would probably help you to name the columns you want rather than using `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `select *`, you can put an alias on the columns as well.

```
SELECT a.title AS 'a_title', b.title AS 'b_title'
-- ...
```

Then your PHP would be something like:

```
$name['a_title']
```

Comment: 38 Seconds, and no orange warning bar. Drats! ;p

Comment: Might be worth explaining *why* not to use SELECT *

Comment: And if I need to retrieve all field? @Matthew

Comment: You would have to write them all out, if the rest of the columns contain redundant data (`a.foo`=`b.foo`), then you can lazily do `SELECT a.*, b.title AS 'b_title', c.title AS 'c_title', ...`, writing out the columns you want explicitly will elminate any ambiguity that can arise from having similar column names.  I always do that even if I think column names will be unique because it is resistant to database schema changes (ie table "b" gets a new column with a name that table "a" contains).  Also always specifying the column names will reduce the amount of data sent, if you don't need it all.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias

```
SELECT  a.title AS TitleA,
        b.title AS TitleB,
        ...
```

FROM     ...

Then reference the alias:

```
$name['TitleA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `SELECT *`!

Explicitly list your columns, which will then allow you to alias them as needed.

```
SELECT a.title AS TableATitle, b.title AS TableBTitle, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SELECT *, you will have to call out the fields by name.  When you do this, you can assign an alias to be used for each.

```
SELECT a.title AS aTitle, b.title AS bTitle, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, a.title as atitle, b.title as btitle
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON  a.someColumn = b.otherColumn
INNER JOIN tableC c
ON b.anotherColumn = c.nextColumn
```